# Generate excel sheet with cell containing both plain text and hyperlinks using Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm looking for a way to generate an excel with one cell containing both plain text and hyperlinks using Java. Here is an example of what is needed:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xoY9.png)
[image]

I've been looking through POI-XSSF but with no success. I manage to fill the cell with plain text or with an hyperlink, but not with both. Has somebody faced a similar issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office Open XML file format `*.xlsx` is not able to store sheet cell contents having multiple hyperlinks in different parts of the text cell content. A hyperlink only refers to the entire cell. (OOXML: `<hyperlink ref="C6" ...>`, `C6` is the cell where the hyperlink refers to). But Apache POI generates Office Open XML file format `*.xlsx`. So what you want is not possible.

I suspect your screen shot comes from OpenOffice or LibreOffice Calc. The native file format of OpenOffice or LibreOffice Calc is Open Document Format  for spreadsheets `*.ods`. This format is able to store sheet cell contents having multiple hyperlinks in different parts of the text cell content. But Apache POI is not made to generate Open Document Format.

One might think: What about creating sheet cell contents having multiple hyperlinks in different parts of the text cell content using OpenOffice or LibreOffice Calc and then save that file as `*.xlsx`? But that will omit the links since `*.xlsx` is not able to store that. You see that if you close the file after saving as `*.xlsx` and then reopen it in Calc. The links are gone. OpenOffice and LibreOffice warns about these disadvantage while saving a file in Office Open XML file format and suggests using Open Document Format instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The screenshot comes from Google Docs. When I downloaded this file in .xlsx format and opened it in Excel, it indeed exhibits the behavior that you mentioned. I had my doubts that there would be a way, but you never know :-)